# Does sorting help efficiency of grep in Perl

Tags: perl, grep

I'm looking for some specifics about how Perl's `grep` function works. I'm doing this:

```
if ( grep{ $foo == $_ } @bar ) {
  some code;
}
```

Suppose `@bar` is large (hundreds of thousands of elements). With my data, if I sort `@bar`, values of `$foo` are more likely to appear near the beginning of the array than near the end. I'm wondering if this will help performance.

Put differently, with the above code, does `grep` move sequentially through `@bar` checking whether `$foo == $_` and then immediately exit once any value has been found to be true? Or would it actually check every element of `@bar` before returning a value?

Comment: good question. I think, that you need to use not `grep`, but `for ()` for your early exit

Comment: And see my comment below. `List::MoreUtils` on CPAN can do what you want, if I right understand your task

Comment: @loldop You should put this as an answer. Seems like `firstidx` would do what I want.

Comment: @user1937198: no, in the demonstrated usage, it returns a *count* of elements where the condition was true, and it could be optimized to stop early in boolean context if there were not the possibility of side effects

Comment: note that firstidx will be *much slower* than grep; only use it if grep is taking too long and you can benchmark an improvement

Comment: @itzy Will you be performing more tests? If so, creating a hash might be a good idea.

Comment: @TLP, not it's just a one-time check. Thanks though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`grep` does not short-circuit, so ordering of elements does not matter.

While List::MoreUtils's `first` does short-circuit, the whole list must be placed on the stack before it's called.

This will be best:

```
for (@bar) {
   if ($foo == $_) {
      some code;
      last;
   }
}
```

**Updated**: I originally iterated over the indexes since that uses O(1) memory, but so does `for (@bar)` (as opposed to `for (LIST)` in general) as ysth reminded me.

Comment: Are you sure using indexes will be faster than using the elements directly?

Comment: @TLP, Won't put the array on the stack. Memory wise, yes. Speed, maybe a itsy tiny bit slower from the singular extra op.

Comment: for on an array won't put the array on the stack

Comment: `first` is very likely to be faster even with the stack copy. Memory could be an issue, but "if it fits in memory once, it will fit twice" is a good enough first approximation.

Comment: @hobbs, Why would doing more be faster?! It does the same thing plus a whole bunch of function calls.

Comment: @ikegami : I have not heard of arrays being moved to stack during some operations. Can you point me to some link which will help in knowing more abt this?

Comment: @Guru, Arrays evaluate to a list of their elements in scalar context. Surely that's in perldata? `for (@a)` is special-cased to pass a reference to `@a` instead of creating a list as documented. This optimisation is not documented.

Comment: `$comment[$this-1] =~ s/scalar context/list context/;`

Answer (score 6):

Since your usage of `grep` is in scalar context, it is returning the number of matching elements. To calculate this, Perl has to visit each element anyway, so it's unlikely that sorting would help performance from this angle.

Comment: Maybe [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils) can help in this situation? Not sure

Comment: @loldop I think so! I'm not particularly familiar with this module, but it seems to be very well constructed and List::MoreUtils::any would be useful here.

Comment: `grep` checks all of the list elements *regardless* of context. It simply returns a list in list context and a count in scalar context. `first` and similar are a bad choice here as the entire list is copied to the parameters of the function, which is a big deal for hundreds of thousands of scalars. The best solution is a simple `for` loop with a `last` once the condition has been satisfied. A loop like that will terminate sooner if the match is near the beginning of the list, and if it can be detected that the loop has gone beyond any potential match.

Answer (score 2):

In your example **grep** will iterate whole array regardless how many elements matched.

If you are able to keep this array sorted - its faster to search for your values using binary search. Also you can convert your array into hash (with keys = array element) and do your checks with constant time, but this will eat additional memory.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to your question

> With my data, if I sort @bar, values of $foo are more likely to appear near the beginning of the array than near the end. I'm wondering if this will help performance.

If the list is sorted in numerical order then you can write

```
sub contains {
  my ($list, $item) = @_;
  for (@$item) {
    return $_ == $item if $_ >= $item;
  }
  return !1;
}

some_code() if contains(\@bar, $foo);
```

Comment: If the list is sorted you can use bsearch and find result way faster. Also, `return;` returns empty list or undef, while `return $_ == $item` returns 1 or "", so this sub has 4 different returning values, thats bad.

Comment: If the list is sorted, you can use a binary search.

Comment: @ikegami: Yes, that is true too of course. PSIAlt also felt he had to point this out. The OP asked whether sorting the data would improve the performance of `grep`, and my answer is *“No, but it would help for a hand-coded equivalent like this (and many others)”*

Comment: And I'm saying your answer is: "You're having performance issues, so why don't you use something that might not be faster at all when there exists something much much faster."

Comment: @ikegami: No, you are very wrong again. I am more than happy with my answer as it is.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. A `grep { $x == $_ } @a` does not benefit from branch prediction, but `grep { $x < $_ } @a` does!

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::HiRes qw( clock_gettime CLOCK_MONOTONIC );

use constant MIN => 0;
use constant MAX => 1000;
use constant AVG => int(MIN  + (MAX - MIN) / 2);
use constant N_LOOPS => 40000;
use constant ARRAY_LEN => 10000;

## is grep faster for sorted arrays?

##
## RANDOM ARRAY VALUES
##
my $n = 0;
my @a = map { int(rand() * (MAX - MIN) + MIN) } 1 .. ARRAY_LEN;
my $duration = -clock_gettime ( CLOCK_MONOTONIC );
for(my $i = 0; $i < N_LOOPS; $i++) {
    $n += grep { AVG < $_ } @a;
}
$duration += clock_gettime ( CLOCK_MONOTONIC );
print "duration: $duration secs, n = $n".$/;

##
## PREDICTABLE ARRAY VALUES
##
$n = 0;
@a = sort {$a <=> $b} @a;
$duration = -clock_gettime ( CLOCK_MONOTONIC );
for(my $i = 0; $i < N_LOOPS; $i++) {
    $n += grep { AVG < $_ } @a;
}
$duration += clock_gettime ( CLOCK_MONOTONIC );
print "duration: $duration secs, n = $n".$/;

## and now we try to eliminate side effects by repeating

##
## RANDOM ARRAY VALUES
##
$n = 0;
@a = map { int(rand() * (MAX - MIN) + MIN) } 1 .. ARRAY_LEN;
$duration = -clock_gettime ( CLOCK_MONOTONIC );
for(my $i = 0; $i < N_LOOPS; $i++) {
    $n += grep { AVG < $_ } @a;
}   
$duration += clock_gettime ( CLOCK_MONOTONIC );
print "duration: $duration secs, n = $n".$/; 

##
## PREDICTABLE ARRAY VALUES
##
$n = 0;
@a = sort {$a <=> $b} @a;
$duration = -clock_gettime ( CLOCK_MONOTONIC );
for(my $i = 0; $i < N_LOOPS; $i++) {
    $n += grep { AVG < $_ } @a;
}   
$duration += clock_gettime ( CLOCK_MONOTONIC );
print "duration: $duration secs, n = $n".$/;
```

The results:

```
duration: 27.7465513650095 secs, n = 199880000 <-- unsorted
duration: 26.129752348992 secs, n = 199880000  <-- sorted
duration: 28.3962040760089 secs, n = 202920000 <-- unsorted
duration: 26.082420132996 secs, n = 202920000  <-- sorted
```

See also [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)

Comment: As ikegami points out, `grep` will walk over every item in the list. It is independent of the conditional.

Comment: Nope. The first argument to grep decides which side of the branch *inside grep* will be taken: add the element to the result list or not.